# IBM Rational Test WorkBench server cannot be connected

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, rational-test-workbench

I want to test an app using IBM Test workbench and have tried following steps from the [IBM tutorial](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.mob.wl.ditaval.doc/topics/t_rec_test_wb.html)

The problem is the device is unable to connect to the server please find the screens shot below:
[image]

1. Installed workbench in my Eclipse
2. Installed IBM rational test on android device
3. Add Device in workbench
4. Scanned QR code from Eclipse workbench and then the server does not connect!

All this process is working fine on the Emulator (may be because the workbench and emulator are on same network.

I have even tried making my device as the wifi hotspot and the laptop shares device's internet.
Still not luck.
Can someone help me with this please? How can I get the device connected to workbench server?

Comment: Why Rational Test Workbench? For Worklight you nee to use "Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight". Make sure you have installed the correct Eclipse plug-in(!). Read the user documentation: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_install_imtww.html

Answer (score 0):

Many reasons could be led to this kind of issue

- be sure that your device is on the same network. In the connection wizard, you have a page with all the possible ip address (the one where you have the QRCode). You can try other possibilities by selecting another ip address in this page
- verify that your firewall doesn't prevent your device to be connected on RTW server (simply deactivate it for some minutes to make the test)

Alternatively, in order to verify the connectivity between the device and the RTW server, open a browser on you device and go the the RTW server address: you should see a web page displayed on your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried to open the RTW server on my browser, but it does not open on my device. AFAIK I m trying to figure out if MAC binding of my laptop has anything to do with this. As I am in a client network, since my device is not mac binded it is not getting through. I would try it on my home network.